# Gathering data by paired columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm having trouble in shaping my `dataframe`.
Here's an example:

```
id  institution name1         id1   name2           id2
1   usp         Miles Davis   123   Arturo Sandoval 111
2   unb         Chet Baker    321   Clifford Brown  121
3   usp         Wayne Shorter 222   Hermeto Pascoal 322
4   Puc-rio     John Coltrane 333   Charlie Parker  112
```

I need to keep the `id` and `institution` columns and gather the other ones like this:

```
id  institution name_all        id_all
1   usp         Miles Davis     123
1   usp         Arturo Sandoval 111
2   unb         Chet Baker      321
2   unb         Clifford Brown  121
3   usp         Wayne Shorter   222
3   usp         Hermeto Pascoal 322
4   Puc-rio     John Coltrane   333
4   Puc-rio     Charlie Parker  112
```

I'm using the `gather` function from the `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
gather(name_all, id_all, -id, -institution)
```

but it comes like this:

```
id  institution name    id
1   usp         name1   Miles Davis
1   usp         id1     123
2   unb         name1   Chet Baker
2   unb         id2     121
```

Any ideas on how to pair those values? I have more than 5 columns to do so, I think that I'm missing an argument to specify which one of them are paired. I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that there is a more elegant solution, but you can try:

```
df %>%
 gather(var, name_all, -matches("id|institution")) %>%
 gather(var2, val, -c(id, institution, var, name_all)) %>%
 mutate(id_all = ifelse(parse_number(var) == parse_number(var2), val, NA)) %>%
 na.omit() %>%
 select(-var, -var2, -val) %>%
 arrange(id)

  id institution        name_all id_all
1  1         usp     Miles_Davis    123
2  1         usp Arturo_Sandoval    111
3  2         unb      Chet_Baker    321
4  2         unb  Clifford_Brown    121
5  3         usp   Wayne_Shorter    222
6  3         usp Hermeto_Pascoal    322
7  4     Puc-rio   John_Coltrane    333
8  4     Puc-rio  Charlie_Parker    112
```

First, it transforms the data from wide to long, excluding the variables that are named institution or id. Second, it performs a second wide-to-long transformation to have all the numbered "id" variables and their values as separate rows. Third, it checks whether the "name" variable has the number as the "id variable. If so, it assigns the appropriate value, otherwise NA. Finally, it removes the rows with NAs, the redundant variables and arranges the data.

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
                 id  institution name1         id1   name2           id2
                 1   usp         Miles_Davis   123   Arturo_Sandoval 111
                 2   unb         Chet_Baker    321   Clifford_Brown  121
                 3   usp         Wayne_Shorter 222   Hermeto_Pascoal 322
                 4   Puc-rio     John_Coltrane 333   Charlie_Parker  112", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi there! I've tried to use your code but it says that there is no function called "matches". And if you don't mind, i'll repeat what i have said to another answer:
 Is there a way to set them manually? Because the columns i want to gather do not follow any logic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For a `tidyverse` solution, you can:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(ColType, ColValue, -id, -institution) %>% 
  mutate(id_number = gsub("^(\\D*)(\\d*)$", "\\2", ColType, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE),
         ColType = gsub("^(\\D*)(\\d*)$", "\\1", ColType, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
         ) %>% 
  spread(ColType, ColValue) %>% 
  select(-id_number)
```